# Can't reinstall OS X 10.9.5 Mavericks

Tags: macos, install

I updated a 2009 MacBook to OS X 10.9.5. It was running a version of 10.9, but I don't recall which one. After the update, commands like `ls` went missing. I tried a *Repair Permissions* via Disk Utility, but it was no help. I'm guessing it was a botched update.

I'm trying to perform a reinstall *without* the DVD. I'm following [Reinstall OS X Without CD/DVD or Apple ID](https://superuser.com/q/959422) (but I have the Apple ID). I boot with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and I jump through all the hoops.

At the final install step, I receive an error ***The item is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later***. I've been trying to do this for the last 2 hours or so, so I'm guessing its not going to be available anytime soon.

I found one previous question for [The item is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later](https://www.google.com/search?q="The+item+is+temporarily+unavailable.+Please+try+again+later"). Unfortunately, none of the answers really provide instructions on how to proceed. They are more like guesses at what could be wrong, and prayers hoping things will correct themselves.

How do I proceed?

---

I have two MacBooks. One is the MacBook discussed above, and the other is a MacBook Pro. Both of them are now broken due to Apple processes. I *really* need one of them to work.

Comment: Are you able to reinstall from the App Store? Under purchases the OS should appear.

Comment: Most common cause of `ls` not working would appear to be that the path was overwritten. Page full of google results would agree - https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ls+command+not+found+mac+os+x&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Yv10Voy8H-Gq8werl5uQBA